# pyinstaller app blocked by administrator (AppLocker). How do i get around this?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe, applocker

I have a pyinstaller exe program which I made to run my python program on my super locked down school issued windows laptop. When I run it on my school computer, I get the popup, "this app has been blocked by your system administrator."

I made an installer and that is also blocked. I also tried to edit some whitelisted files to run my app but that didn't work either. I don't get how some installers like the rainmeter installer work but mine doesn't, because rainmeter definitely isn't whitelisted. I'm wondering if there is a way to bypass AppLocker so I can install my program.

if it helps, here is my python program. It's a stock trading app that connects to a server on my desktop to run an algorithm.

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import customtkinter as tk

# sets apperence properties for the window
tk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
tk.set_default_color_theme("green")


class App(tk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.configureWindow()
        self.declareSidebarFrame()
        self.declareGraph()
        self.declareTabView()
        self.declareBuyingFrame()

    def configureWindow(self):
        self.title("BuyIn")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # sets properties for the window
        tk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        tk.set_default_color_theme("green")

    def changeAppearanceMode(self, newAppearanceMode):
        tk.set_appearance_mode(newAppearanceMode)

        # change graph color
        if tk.get_appearance_mode() == "Light":
            facecolor = "#ebebeb"
            tick_label_color = "black"
            self.plot.plot(color="#2fa572")
        else:
            facecolor = "#242424"
            tick_label_color = "white"
            self.plot.plot(color="#2fa572")

        self.fig.set_facecolor(facecolor)
        self.plot.set_facecolor(facecolor)
        self.plot.tick_params(labelcolor=tick_label_color)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def declareSidebarFrame(self):
        # declare sidebar frame
        self.sidebarFrame = tk.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebarFrame.grid(rowspan=2, row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebarFrame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        # declare app title
        self.logoLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.sidebarFrame,
            text="Buy In\nbeta",
            font=tk.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"),
        )
        self.logoLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        # create app apperence modes
        self.appearanceModeLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.sidebarFrame, text="Appearance Mode:"
        )
        self.appearanceModeLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=(0, 10))
        self.appearanceModeOptionMenu = tk.CTkOptionMenu(
            self.sidebarFrame,
            values=["Light", "Dark"],
            command=self.changeAppearanceMode,
        )
        self.appearanceModeOptionMenu.grid(
            row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=(0, 10))

    def declareGraph(self):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.plot = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        self.fig.set_facecolor("#242424")
        self.plot.set_facecolor("#242424")
        self.plot.tick_params(labelcolor="white")
        self.plot.plot(color="#2fa572")
        self.plot.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def declareTabView(self):
        self.tabview = tk.CTkTabview(self, width=400)
        self.tabview.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(0, 20), pady=(10, 0))

        self.tabview.add("Stock Trading")
        self.tabview.add("Crypto Trading")
        self.tabview.add("Auto Trading")

        # declare 'Stock Trading' objects
        self.dtTickerEntryBox = tk.CTkEntry(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"), placeholder_text="Ticker"
        )
        self.dtTickerEntryBox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.dtDurationBox = tk.CTkOptionMenu(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"),
            values=["60m", "3h", "6h", "12h", "1d", "3d"],
        )
        self.dtDurationBox.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.dtDurationBox.set("3h")
        self.dtButton = tk.CTkButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"),
            text="Find Matches",
            command=self.stockTradingAlgorithem,
        )
        self.dtButton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))

        self.dtDataSizeLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"), text="Database Size - Result Size"
        )
        self.dtDataSizeLabel.grid(
            row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=(10, 0))

        self.dtDataSizeSlider = tk.CTkSlider(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"), from_=1, to=100
        )
        self.dtDataSizeSlider.grid(
            row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.dtResultSizeSlider = tk.CTkSlider(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"), from_=1, to=20
        )
        self.dtResultSizeSlider.grid(
            row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=(10, 0)
        )
        self.dtResultSizeSlider.configure(number_of_steps=4)

        self.dtGraphModeLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"), text="Graph Mode"
        )
        self.dtGraphModeLabel.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.dtRepeatAlgorithemVariable = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.dtRepeatAlgorithem = tk.CTkRadioButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"),
            text="Repeat Graph",
            variable=self.dtRepeatAlgorithemVariable,
            value=0,
        )
        self.dtRepeatAlgorithem.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, sticky="w")
        self.dtSingleAlgorithem = tk.CTkRadioButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"),
            text="Run Once",
            variable=self.dtRepeatAlgorithemVariable,
            value=1,
        )
        self.dtSingleAlgorithem.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=10, sticky="w")

        global dtLiveAlgorithemUpdates
        dtLiveAlgorithemUpdates = tk.CTkTextbox(
            self.tabview.tab("Stock Trading"), width=225, height=100
        )
        dtLiveAlgorithemUpdates.grid(
            row=3, rowspan=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10
        )

        # declare 'Crypto Trading' objects
        self.ctTickerEntryBox = tk.CTkEntry(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"), placeholder_text="Ticker"
        )
        self.ctTickerEntryBox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.ctDurationBox = tk.CTkOptionMenu(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"), values=["60m", "3h", "6h", "12h"]
        )
        self.ctDurationBox.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.ctDurationBox.set("3h")
        self.ctButton = tk.CTkButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"),
            text="Find Matches",
            command=self.cryptoTradingAlgorithem,
        )
        self.ctButton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))

        self.ctDataSizeLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"), text="Database Size - Result Size"
        )
        self.ctDataSizeLabel.grid(
            row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=(10, 0))

        self.ctDataSizeSlider = tk.CTkSlider(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"), from_=1, to=3
        )
        self.ctDataSizeSlider.grid(
            row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.ctResultSizeSlider = tk.CTkSlider(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"), from_=1, to=20
        )
        self.ctResultSizeSlider.grid(
            row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=(10, 0)
        )
        self.ctResultSizeSlider.configure(number_of_steps=4)

        self.ctGraphModeLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"), text="Graph Mode"
        )
        self.ctGraphModeLabel.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.ctRepeatAlgorithemVariable = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.ctRepeatAlgorithem = tk.CTkRadioButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"),
            text="Repeat Graph",
            variable=self.ctRepeatAlgorithemVariable,
            value=0,
        )
        self.ctRepeatAlgorithem.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, sticky="w")
        self.ctSingleAlgorithem = tk.CTkRadioButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"),
            text="Run Once",
            variable=self.ctRepeatAlgorithemVariable,
            value=1,
        )
        self.ctSingleAlgorithem.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=10, sticky="w")

        global ctLiveAlgorithemUpdates
        ctLiveAlgorithemUpdates = tk.CTkTextbox(
            self.tabview.tab("Crypto Trading"), width=225, height=100
        )
        ctLiveAlgorithemUpdates.grid(
            row=3, rowspan=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10
        )

        # declare 'Auto Trading' objects
        self.atTickerEntryBox = tk.CTkEntry(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"), placeholder_text="Ticker"
        )
        self.atTickerEntryBox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.atButton = tk.CTkButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"),
            text="Start Auto Trading",
            command=self.autoTradingAlgorithem,
        )
        self.atButton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.atButton = tk.CTkButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"),
            text="Stop Auto Trading",
            fg_color="#3b3b3b",
        )
        self.atButton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))

        self.atDataSizeLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"), text="Database Size - Result Size"
        )
        self.atDataSizeLabel.grid(
            row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=(10, 0))

        self.atDataSizeSlider = tk.CTkSlider(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"), from_=1, to=100
        )
        self.atDataSizeSlider.grid(
            row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.atResultSizeSlider = tk.CTkSlider(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"), from_=1, to=20
        )
        self.atResultSizeSlider.grid(
            row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=(10, 0)
        )
        self.atResultSizeSlider.configure(number_of_steps=4)

        self.atTradingModeLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"), text="Trading Mode"
        )
        self.atTradingModeLabel.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=(10, 0))
        self.tradingMode = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.atPaperTradingButton = tk.CTkRadioButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"),
            text="Paper Trading",
            variable=self.tradingMode,
            value=0,
        )
        self.atPaperTradingButton.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, sticky="w")
        self.atLiveTradingButton = tk.CTkRadioButton(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"),
            text="Live Trading",
            variable=self.tradingMode,
            value=1,
        )
        self.atLiveTradingButton.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=10, sticky="w")

        global atLiveTradingUpdates
        atLiveTradingUpdates = tk.CTkTextbox(
            self.tabview.tab("Auto Trading"), width=225, height=100
        )
        atLiveTradingUpdates.grid(
            row=3, rowspan=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10
        )

    def declareBuyingFrame(self):
        # declare buying frame
        self.buyingFrame = tk.CTkFrame(self, width=400)
        self.buyingFrame.grid(
            row=1, column=2, padx=(0, 20), pady=(10, 40), sticky="nsew"
        )

        # declare stock purchasing objects
        self.tickerEntryBoxLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.buyingFrame, text="Stock Ticker")
        self.tickerEntryBoxLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
        self.tickerEntryBox = tk.CTkEntry(
            self.buyingFrame, width=125, state="disabled")
        self.tickerEntryBox.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)

        self.sharesEntryBoxLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.buyingFrame, text="Quantity")
        self.sharesEntryBoxLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10)
        self.sharesEntryBox = tk.CTkEntry(
            self.buyingFrame, width=125, state="disabled")
        self.sharesEntryBox.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10)

        self.orderTypeBoxLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.buyingFrame, text="Order Type")
        self.orderTypeBoxLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
        self.orderTypeBox = tk.CTkOptionMenu(
            self.buyingFrame,
            values=["Limit", "Market", "Stop"],
            width=125,
            state="disabled",
        )
        self.orderTypeBox.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)

        self.Button = tk.CTkButton(
            self.buyingFrame,
            text="Buy Stock",
            width=125,
            command=self.stockTradingAlgorithem,
            state="disabled",
        )
        self.Button.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10)

        # declare stock purchasing mode objects
        self.tradingModeLabel = tk.CTkLabel(
            self.buyingFrame, text="Trading Mode")
        self.tradingModeLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)
        self.tradingMode = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        self.paperMode = tk.CTkRadioButton(
            self.buyingFrame, text="Paper", variable=self.tradingMode, value=0
        )
        self.paperMode.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=(10, 0),
                            pady=(10, 0), sticky="w")
        self.liveMode = tk.CTkRadioButton(
            self.buyingFrame, text="Live", variable=self.tradingMode, value=1
        )
        self.liveMode.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=(
            10, 0), pady=(10, 0), sticky="w")

    def serverRequest(self, settings):
        import socket

        # Define the server's external IP address and port
        server_external_ip = '192.168.50.43'
        server_port = 12345

        # Create a socket and connect to the server
        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client_socket.connect((server_external_ip, server_port))

        try:
            # Send data to the server for evaluation
            client_socket.send(settings.encode())

            # Receive the result from the server
            result = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            print(f"Received result from server: {result}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
        finally:
            # Close the client socket
            client_socket.close()

    def stockTradingAlgorithem(self):
        if self.dtRepeatAlgorithemVariable.get() == 0:
            repeatNumber = 10
        else:
            repeatNumber = 1

        for i in range(repeatNumber):
            # define object atributers
            settings = self.dtTickerEntryBox.get(), int(self.dtResultSizeSlider.get()), int(
                self.dtDataSizeSlider.get()), self.dtDurationBox.get(), "Ticker"
            print(settings)
            print(settings[0])

            # clear graph
            self.plot.cla()

            # send request
            averageResult, tickerData = self.serverRequest(self, settings)

            if tk.get_appearance_mode() == "Light":
                self.plot.plot(averageResult.mean(axis=1), color="black")
            else:
                self.plot.plot(averageResult.mean(axis=1), color="white")

            self.plot.plot(
                tickerData["Close"].reset_index(drop=True), color="#2fa572", linewidth=3
            )
            self.canvas.draw()

            App()

    def cryptoTradingAlgorithem(self):
        if self.ctRepeatAlgorithemVariable.get() == 0:
            repeatNumber = 20
        else:
            repeatNumber = 1

        for i in range(repeatNumber):
            # define object atributers
            settings = self.ctTickerEntryBox.get(), int(self.ctResultSizeSlider.get()), int(
                self.ctDataSizeSlider.get()), self.ctDurationBox.get(), "Crypto"

            # clear graph
            self.plot.cla()

            # send request
            averageResult, tickerData = self.serverRequest(self, settings)

            if tk.get_appearance_mode() == "Light":
                self.plot.plot(averageResult.mean(axis=1), color="black")
            else:
                self.plot.plot(averageResult.mean(axis=1), color="white")

            self.plot.plot(
                tickerData["Close"].reset_index(drop=True), color="#2fa572", linewidth=3
            )
            self.canvas.draw()

            App()

    def autoTradingAlgorithem(self):
        while self.marketOpenCheck(datetime.now()) == True:
            # define object atributers
            settings = self.dtTickerEntryBox.get(), int(self.dtResultSizeSlider.get()), int(
                self.dtDataSizeSlider.get()), self.dtDurationBox.get(), "Ticker"

            # clear graph
            self.plot.cla()

            # send request
            averageResult, tickerData = self.serverRequest(self, settings)

            if tk.get_appearance_mode() == "Light":
                self.plot.plot(averageResult.mean(axis=1), color="black")
            else:
                self.plot.plot(averageResult.mean(axis=1), color="white")

            self.plot.plot(
                tickerData["Close"].reset_index(drop=True), color="#2fa572", linewidth=3
            )
            self.canvas.draw()

            App()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why aren't you using your own computer? Does your school only allow you to connect to their network with their computer?

Comment: The only laptop I have is my school laptop unfortunately. I might have to buy a cheap one if I can't figure this out.

Comment: I think this is probably more about your specific OS and/or security addons, not python per se. And a technical solution runs the risk of getting you in trouble for unauthorized access. This probably requires a social solution, i.e., ask whoever provisioned your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my system administrators only blocked exe's from running in documents, so it worked fine in downloads.